# useing my own db $info to replace parts of a url and open in a iframe

Tags: php, mysql, html, url, replace

this dont work any options please?

"Result below if printed"

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=WYOMING,WYOMING,MI&zoom=14&size=500x500&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue|label:S|42.902160,-85.696708&sensor=false

need to replace parts of url like shown above to enter "result" into an iframe src= ????

test page= findmeaload.com/ZipFind/frame.php

Comment: Can you please be a bit more... lucid in your description what you want to achieve? :)

Comment: Database, URL, iFrame -- 3 things that have nothing to do with each other. WTF are you asking?

Comment: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=WYOMING,WYOMING,MI&zoom=14&size=500x500&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue|label:S|42.902160,-85.696708&sensor=false

if i put this in a iframe it comes up with the map comes from this

 print ("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="); echo $city; print(","); echo $city; print(","); echo $state; print("&zoom=14&size=500x500&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue|label:S|"); echo $lat; print(","); echo $lon; print("&sensor=false");
script calls for entry of city and state to get info from db
so i need to get end url into iframe

Comment: test page http://findmeaload.com/ZipFind/frame.php

Answer (score 0):

For one, that's a hideous blob of text to look at. Why bother with the various echoes, when print with double-quotes is perfectly capable of doing the variable insertion itself?

```
print("http://maps.google.com/maps/etc....?center={$City},{$City},{$State}&zoom=etc....");
```

And hitting your test page spits out the following URL near the top:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=,,&zoom=14&size=500x500&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue|label:S|,&sensor=false
```

notice the `center=,,`... there's no City or State there, so your $City and $State variables are empty/null. In your comment you use $city and $state - remember that PHP variable names are case sensitive, such that $City is something completely different from $city.

Comment: yeah still in the works this is the second one i have made still have to go thro it thanks for that tho still looking how to get it in iframe so it loads the map